# Change many parent properties without writing them all out

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

Is there a way for me to associate the values in Warrior.stats with the values in Character.stats without writing the following for every instance of character?

```
this.level = 4,
this.vitality = 11,
etc...
```

In other words, always write CharacterChild.stats as an array of numbers.

```
class Character {
    constructor(name, sex, gift, physique, stats) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.gift = gift;
        this.physique = physique;
        this.stats = ['level', 
                      'vitality', 
                      'attunement', 
                      'endurance', 
                      'strength', 
                      'dexterity', 
                      'resistance', 
                      'intellegence', 
                      'faith', 
                      'humanity']
    }
}
class Warrior extends Character {
    constructor(name, sex, gift, physique, stats){
        super(name, sex, gift, physique, stats)
        this.stats = [4, 11, 8, 12, 13, 13, 11, 9, 9]
    }
 }

let dave = new Warrior('pla','ce','hold','er')
return dave.stats.level
//4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use rest and spread:

```
class Warrior extends Character {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
```

Another option would be to use class fields for the `this.stats` and omit a constructor entirely (`super` will be called automatically, with the same parameters as the subclass was called with):

```
class Warrior extends Character {
    stats = [4, 11, 8, 12, 13, 13, 11, 9, 9]
}
```

Comment: Neither of those worked, I added a line at the bottom to clarify. I want to be able to retrieve stats from the warrior class with `warrior.stats.level`

Comment: The `stats` property in both the superclass and the subclass is an array, not an object, so `this.stats.level` won't work. Assign an object instead? `stats = { level: 4, vitality: 11,` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```js
this.stats = [4, 11, 8, 12, 13, 13, 11, 9, 9]
```

which overwrites your `stats` array of property names, with this:

```js
[4, 11, 8, 12, 13, 13, 11, 9, 9].forEach((val, i) => {
  this[this.stats[i]] = val;
});
```

which will produce the desired result:

```js
this.level = 4, this.vitality = 11, ..., this.humanity = 9
```

```js
class Character {
  constructor(name, sex, gift, physique, stats) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.gift = gift;
    this.physique = physique;
    this.stats = ['level',
      'vitality',
      'attunement',
      'endurance',
      'strength',
      'dexterity',
      'resistance',
      'intellegence',
      'faith',
      'humanity'
    ]
  }
}
class Warrior extends Character {
  constructor(name, sex, gift, physique, stats) {
    super(name, sex, gift, physique, stats);
    
    // map values to stats names
    [4, 11, 8, 12, 13, 13, 11, 9, 9]
      .forEach((val, i) => {
        this[this.stats[i]] = val;
    });
  }
}

let dave = new Warrior('pla', 'ce', 'hold', 'er')
console.log(dave);
```